# Where is travis-CI expecting the artifacts on deployment?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to set-up the deployment of binary files (after tests) on Amazon S3. The travis-ci [documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/) is useless because it doesn't mention where should the artifacts be generated/copied so that travis can upload them to the specific bucket. Any idea? Is there any 'well known" path there it looks for artifacts?

```
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: "YOUR AWS ACCESS KEY"
  secret_access_key: "YOUR AWS SECRET KEY"
  bucket: "S3 Bucket"
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

Answer (score 2):

The deployment will look at directories or files relative to the current working directory, which is the project's root normally, unless it's somehow changed as part of the build. If you don't specify a directory, Travis CI will deploy the entire project folder to S3.

So if your project creates an artifact in the `dist` directory, you can specify the relative path:

```
deploy:
  provider: s3
  local-dir: dist
```

Read more [here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/#S3-bucket-regions)

Comment: Edit must be at least 6 chars, but I just want to improve on the above "local-dir" which is not yml-format.

It should be local_dir, or "global.local_dir".

EDIT: Now fixed!